# How can I add another TextInput by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a beginner in React Native and struggling with adding another TextInput ( as a component) by clicking a button then putting those Components in a flat list

Here's my main screen

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    FlatList
} from 'react-native'
import InputDemo from '../components/InputDemo'

const AddInputDemo = props => {
    const addInput = () => {
        //....
    }
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Button
                title='Add a location'
                onPress={addInput}
            />
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                data={} // I really can't figure it out what to put in this prop
                renderItem={itemData => (
                    <InputDemo />
                )}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default AddInputDemo;
```

Here's my InputDemo Component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    Button
} from 'react-native'

const InputDemo = props => {
    return(
        <View>
            <TextInput
                placeholder='Search'
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default InputDemo;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the **data** prop of the **FlatList** is the array of items you want to the **FlatList** to use, and **renderItem** is a function that is called for each item in the **data** prop that you provide.

for your quetion, you need to use state and setState to track the number of inputs you want to show in the FlatList

```
import { useState } from "react";
const AddInputDemo = props => {
    const [numberOfInputs, setNumberOfInputs] = useState([1]) // initial count is 1, so one input will be displayed

    const addInput = () => {
      setNumberOfInputs([...numberOfInputs, 1]);
    }
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Button
                title='Add a location'
                onPress={addInput}
            />
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                data={numberOfInputs}
                renderItem={itemData => (
// it will be called as many times u increase the numberOfInputs array
                    <InputDemo />
                )}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you so so much Ahmed. It works. I deeply appreciate your help. Have a nice day !

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I discover your approach results a error, since you're adding 1 in an array of numberOfInputs, not increasing it's value by one and put them all in an ascending array. It will make all the id of each InputDemo has the same key: 1. So, inspired by you, I made some changes:

Comment: ```
const [numberOfInputs, setNumberOfInputs] = useState([0]) 
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const addInput = () => {
      setCount(count+1);
      const tempCount = count;
      setNumberOfInputs([...numberOfInputs, tempCount])
      console.log(numberOfInputs);
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, can you help me with this question. It's the same problem with the above question but this time I use the **Class Component**. Would you mind helping me out, please? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/106914927?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

React Native Flatlist takes a `data` array prop. It represents an array, where each element describes one list item, and the array element can be an object that can contain any number of attributes to describe the list element.

Flatlist takes a second prop called `renderItem`, this is a function that renders the list item using a data element.

As you'll see in the example below, we'll configure our data array element with a single attribute called `placeholder` that we'll inject as a prop to the component being rendered in `renderItem`.

```
const AddInputDemo = () => {
    // define your list with a setter in the state
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    const addInput = () => {
        // add a new object to the list and set it to the state
        setList([...list, { placeholder: 'something' }]);
    };

    return (
        <View style={ { flex: 1 } }>
            <Button title="Add a location" onPress={ addInput } />
            {/* add your list to the data prop and setup the */}
            {/* renderItem prop with the list item */}
            <FlatList keyExtractor={ ({ id }) => (id) } data={ list }
                      renderItem={ ({ item }) => (<InputDemo item={ item } />) } />
        </View>
    );
};

const InputDemo = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            {/* use the configured data from the props */}
            <TextInput placeholder={ props.item.placeholder } />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: - Thanks for the great answer. 
- I want to ask another question:
- What if my InputDemo and Main screen are class components (they're in different folders as well).
- How do we pass the props to customize the InputDemo & does the the TextInput needs to be generated with a key prop ? Then how to navigate that key prop to the FlatList component ?

Comment: I think Flatlist takes care of the key for you, as for the first question, it does not matter if it's a class or function component or they're in different files, you can still pass props to it through the `renderItem` prop.

Comment: can you help me with this question. It's the same problem with the above question but this time I use the Class Component. Would you mind helping me out, please? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/106914927?noredirect=1